# Как отобразить картинку при воспроизведении видео?

Tags: html, php, css, javascript

Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы про воспроизведении видео на сайте рядом с этим видео(но не в самом видео)появлялись картинки, то есть чтобы в любом месте сайта в указанную минуту просмотра видео появилась нужная картинка. Возможно такое с помощью какой-то технологии реализовать на сайте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, инфа 100%.

С очень большой вероятностью вы используете сторонний flash плеер (так как если бы был HTML5, то завно уже заюзали бы

```
var curtime = video.currentTime;
```

[video.currentTime](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-currenttime)
).

Почитайте его документацию, скорее всего, там есть выходные параметры конкретного времени. Если нет, смените плеер.